# Error when sign in as different user: The resource cannot be found. /SitePages/Home.aspx

Tags: security, site-template, groups

Create a site collection selecting a site template. Prompted asking whether to use existing groups and gave OK. In the newly created site collection, added new user as member and also in a new user group. But when I sign in as that user, am getting the error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /SitePages/Home.aspx

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you customize your site collection? Error tells you that it cannot find a page or one of its resources (controls, web part error etc...).

Comment: But am able to access all pages when logged in as site owner.

Comment: It can also be a access denied issue by web part or control. Do you customize something on the site?

Comment: I have web parts in the site. rest all created out of box using the site.

Comment: What kind of web part? Content query?

Comment: If the page is edited/customised in any way or if your library has versioning/approval enabled, make sure the page is published and approved. Also, if your page is using a custom page layout, ensure that its published/exists in the root site.